# How to find a normal vector of a vector?

Tags: calculus, vectors

**Problem**

> Find the normal vector $\bf{N}$ to $\bf{r}(t)=\langle t,\cos t \rangle$ at $t=\frac{9\pi}{4}.$
> (Use symbolic notation and fractions where needed.)
> *Feedback:* Recall that the normal vector of $\bf{r}(t)$ is $\bf{T'}(t),$ where $\bf{T}(t)=\frac{\bf{r'}(t)}{||\bf{r'}(t)||}$ is a unit tangent vector.

How do I find this normal vector? So basically I did what the feedback said. I found the derivative of each function in the vector and got.

$$(1, -\sin(t))$$

Then I got the magnitude:

$$\sqrt{1+\sin^2\left(\frac{9\pi \:}{4}\right)}$$

Then I divided everything in my vector by that magnitude while putting in $$\frac{9\pi }{4}$$ like so:

$$\frac{-\sin\left(\frac{9\pi }{4}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2\left(\frac{9\pi \:}{4}\right)}}$$

What my problem? Thank you. Here's my answer:

$$\left\langle\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right\rangle$$

Comment: Did you simplify?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel yes I did, the editor got rid of my screenshot with my answer lemme put it up real quick. okay there's my answer

Comment: What you have got is the unit tangent vector. You need to differentiate that to get the normal vector. The normal vector should come to $(- \sqrt2 / 3 \sqrt3, - 2 / 3 \sqrt3)$.

Comment: @MathLover thx i see now

Comment: Also see [tutorials](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/line-integrals-in-vector-fields-articles/a/constructing-a-unit-normal-vector-to-curve) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit tangent vector is $$T(t)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2(t)}},-\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{\sin^2(t)+1}})$$

So the normal vector of $r(t)$ is $$T'(t)=(-\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin(2t)}{({3-\cos(2t)})^{\frac{3}{2}}},-\frac{\cos(t)}{(1+\sin^{2}(t))^{\frac{3}{2}}})$$

Now let $t=\frac{9\pi}{4}$ and you should get $$T'(\frac{9\pi}{4})=(-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{9},-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}).$$

Comment: ah ok thanks! i see now